# Grouping html elements by attribute value

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I need to convert a HTML file to XML format using XSLT 2.0. Here I need to group p tags with attributes values "**n1**","**n2**","**n3**" etc. as lists with level 1, level 2 and level 3. Below is my input

```
<p class='h1'>the fisr A</p>
<p class='txt'>one</p>
<p class='h2'>the sec sec B</p>
<p class="n1"><span>(a)</span><span>Minimum average</span></p>
<p class="n1"><span>(b)</span><span>Minimum average daily</span></p>
<p class="n1"><span>(c)</span><span>Cooling period.</span></p>
<p class="n1"><span>(d)</span><span>Securities of the company</span></p>
<p class="n2"><span>■</span><span>Th second level list</span><span>.</span></p>
<p class="n2"><span>■</span><span>Th second level list</span></p>
<p class="n3"><span>-</span><span>Th second level list</span><span>.</span></p>
<p class="n3"><span>-</span><span>Th second level list</span></p>
<p class='txt'>the next text</p>
<p class='h3'>the fisr C</p>
<p class='txt'>four</p>
<p class='txt'>five</p>
<p class="n1"><span>(a)</span><span>Minimum average</span></p>
<p class="n1"><span>(b)</span><span>Minimum average daily</span></p>
<p class='h1'>the seccond A</p>
```

**The required output is**

```
<p class="h1">the fisr A</p>
<p class="txt">one</p>
<p class="h2">the sec sec B</p>
<list1>
    <li>
        <span>(a)</span>
        <span>Minimum average</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>(b)</span>
        <span>Minimum average daily</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>(c)</span>
        <span>Cooling period.</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>(d)</span>
        <span>Securities of the company</span>
        <list2>
            <li>
                <span>?</span>
                <span>Th second level list</span>
                <span>.</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>?</span>
                <span>Th second level list</span>
                <list3>
                    <li>
                        <span>-</span>
                        <span>Th second level list</span>
                        <span>.</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>-</span>
                        <span>Th second level list</span>
                    </li>
                </list3>
            </li>
        </list2>
    </li>
</list1>
<p class="txt">the next text</p>
<p class="h3">the fisr C</p>
<p class="txt">four</p>
<p class="txt">five</p>
<list1>
    <li>
        <span>(a)</span>
        <span>Minimum average</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>(b)</span>
        <span>Minimum average daily</span>
    </li>
</list1>
<p class="h1">the seccond A</p>
```

**I used below code. But getting wrong output**

```
   <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="./@class='n1'">
    <list1>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-adjacent="./@class='n2'">
        <list2>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </list2>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </list1>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

`

Anyone may help me for getting the desired output using for-each-group

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code. Click the `<>` snippet editor and give us a [mcve]

Comment: I think this question is clear

Comment: SO is not a "gimme the codez" site. Please show some effort - it will be voted down and closed if not. Just a friendly heads up on how SO works.

Comment: Already I tried this, but I never get the desired output.

Comment: So show us the code that does not work. Perhaps someone can fix it.

Comment: I have used this code, but its producing wrong output<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="./@class='n1'">
    <list1>
      
      <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-adjacent="./@class='n2'">
        <list2>
          
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"></xsl:apply-templates>
          
        </list2>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
      
      
    </list1>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

Comment: Please update the question with formatted code and result - you already show the expected result

Comment: No now it came to end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown any context nor explained the rules, it seems you want to first find adjacent `p` elements with the `class` as `n1, n2, n3` and then write a recursive grouping to get the list nesting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math mf" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element()*">
        <xsl:param name="input" as="element()*"/>
        <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:if test="$input">
            <xsl:element name="list{$level}">
                <xsl:for-each-group select="$input" group-starting-with="p[@class = concat('n', $level)]">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="self::p[@class = concat('n', $level)]">
                            <li>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
                                <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group() except ., $level + 1)"/>
                            </li>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each-group>               
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="@class = ('n1', 'n2', 'n3')">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                        <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group(), 1)"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This transforms

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <p class="h1">the fisr A</p>
    <p class="txt">one</p>
    <p class="h2">the sec sec B</p>
    <p class="n1">
        <span>(a)</span>
        <span>Minimum average</span>
    </p>
    <p class="n1">
        <span>(b)</span>
        <span>Minimum average daily</span>
    </p>
    <p class="n1">
        <span>(c)</span>
        <span>Cooling period.</span>
    </p>
    <p class="n1">
        <span>(d)</span>
        <span>Securities of the company</span>
    </p>
    <p class="n2">
        <span>■</span>
        <span>Th second level list</span>
        <span>.</span>
    </p>
    <p class="n2">
        <span>■</span>
        <span>Th second level list</span>
    </p>
    <p class="n3">
        <span>-</span>
        <span>Th second level list</span>
        <span>.</span>
    </p>
    <p class="n3">
        <span>-</span>
        <span>Th second level list</span>
    </p>
    <p class="txt">the next text</p>
    <p class="h3">the fisr C</p>
    <p class="txt">four</p>
    <p class="txt">five</p>
    <p class="n1">
        <span>(a)</span>
        <span>Minimum average</span>
    </p>
    <p class="n1">
        <span>(b)</span>
        <span>Minimum average daily</span>
    </p>
    <p class="h1">the seccond A</p>
</root>
```

into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <p class="h1">the fisr A</p>
   <p class="txt">one</p>
   <p class="h2">the sec sec B</p>
   <list1>
      <li>
               <span>(a)</span>
               <span>Minimum average</span>
         </li>
      <li>
               <span>(b)</span>
               <span>Minimum average daily</span>
         </li>
      <li>
               <span>(c)</span>
               <span>Cooling period.</span>
         </li>
      <li>
               <span>(d)</span>
               <span>Securities of the company</span>
            <list2>
            <li>
                     <span>■</span>
                     <span>Th second level list</span>
                     <span>.</span>
               </li>
            <li>
                     <span>■</span>
                     <span>Th second level list</span>
                  <list3>
                  <li>
                           <span>-</span>
                           <span>Th second level list</span>
                           <span>.</span>
                     </li>
                  <li>
                           <span>-</span>
                           <span>Th second level list</span>
                     </li>
               </list3>
            </li>
         </list2>
      </li>
   </list1>
   <p class="txt">the next text</p>
   <p class="h3">the fisr C</p>
   <p class="txt">four</p>
   <p class="txt">five</p>
   <list1>
      <li>
               <span>(a)</span>
               <span>Minimum average</span>
         </li>
      <li>
               <span>(b)</span>
               <span>Minimum average daily</span>
         </li>
   </list1>
   <p class="h1">the seccond A</p>
</root>
```